# Section text appears misaligned

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I am a beginner in LaTex and I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, french, greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\title{Physics assignment}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Excercise 1}
\selectlanguage{greek}
$m = 5kg$

$t = 0sec$: $\vec{υ} = 2m/s$

$t' = 2sec$: $\vec{υ} = 12m/s$

$\mu = 0,2$

$\vec{g} = 10m/s^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output of the code. How can I make it so that the first line of the section, "m = 5kg" aligns with the rest of the lines?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are making new paragraphs, paragraphs are indented by default. You should probably put this into a math construction like `align`. Also: look up the `siunitx` package for formatting units, you're doing it wrong here (there are actually rules as to how unites should be formatted and `siunitx` makes this super easy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi @PuperHacker and welcome to TeX-SE.

As you are a beginner let's go step by step.

---

**Standards**

There are many standards around the world. LaTeX's standard depends of the class and *normally* they are related to common standards in USA.
I'm from Brazil and the common standard here (the one taught in elementary schools) is *all paragraphs are indented*.

So, first basic command `\usepackage{indentfirst}`

This is a MWE (Minimum Working Example). OBS: `\usepackage{lipsum}` generates dummy text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %(un)comment this line to test
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \section{title}
    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

With `\usepackage{indentfirst}`

[image]

Without `\usepackage{indentfirst}`

[image]

---

**Equations and Units**

There are many methods to input math into LaTeX.

I must be honest here, I learned about `siunitx` only after I started my own set of units commands, so there might be some better methods to use the package `siunitx`.

For more info, please check: [CTAN - siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

A not so minimal WE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \section{title}
    Text $m = 5 kg$ does not result in the same as $m = 5$ kg.

    With a blank line (not recommended)

    \begin{equation}
    m = 5 kg
    \end{equation}

    Without a blank line (recommended)
    \begin{equation}
    m = 5 kg
    \end{equation}

    Let's test some text commands in math mode.

    Using align
    \begin{align}
    m & = 5 kg                \\
    m & = 5 \operatorname{kg} \\
    m & = 5 \text{kg}         \\
    m & = 5 \textrm{kg}       \\
    m & = 5 \mathrm{kg}
    \end{align}

    Using split
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    m & = 5 kg                \\
    m & = 5 \operatorname{kg} \\
    m & = 5 \text{kg}         \\
    m & = 5 \textrm{kg}       \\
    m & = 5 \mathrm{kg}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}

    Align and split don't interfere with spacing, but they label equations differently.

    \clearpage
    And now some siunitx commands and spacing
    \begin{align}
    m & = 5 \si{\kilogram}        \\
    m & = 5 \ \si{\kilogram}      \\
    m & = 5 \, \si{\kilogram}     \\
    m & = 5 \; \si{\kilogram}     \\
    m & = 5 \quad \si{\kilogram}  \\
    m & = 5 \qquad \si{\kilogram}
    \end{align} 

    And now some siunitx commands to better spacing comparing the ones without it.
    \begin{align}
    m       & = 5\si{\kilogram}            \\
    m       & = \SI{5}{\kilogram}          \\
    \vec{u} & = 12 \si{m/s}                \\
    \vec{u} & = \SI{12}{m/s}               \\
    \vec{u} & = \SI{12}{m \per s}          \\
    \vec{u} & = \SI{12}{\metre\per\second}
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

and the results are

[image]

[image]

In my point of view, `siunitx` has the most options and is a well maintained package. If you do not want to use it, the second best approach would be `\operatorname{}` due the better handling of spacing.

Answer (score 10):

With `align*` and `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, french, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\section*{Excercise 1}
\selectlanguage{greek}

\begin{align*}
m &= \SI{5}{\kg}\\
t &= \SI{0}{\s}: \vec{υ} = \SI{2}{\m\per\s}\\
t' &= \SI{2}{\s}: \vec{υ} = \SI{12}{\m\per\s} \\
\mu &= 0,2\\
\vec{g} &= \SI{10}{\m\per\s\squared}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you will want to align to the `=` sign, as was shown by leandris.  Occasionally, however, you may wish to align to both the left side of the variables AND the `=` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, french, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\section*{Exercise 1}
\selectlanguage{greek}
\[
\TABbinary
\setstackaligngap{0pt}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\alignCenterstack{
&m&=& \SI{5}{\kg}\\
&t&=& \SI{0}{\s}: \vec{υ} = \SI{2}{\m\per\s}\\
&t'&=& \SI{2}{\s}: \vec{υ} = \SI{12}{\m\per\s} \\
&\mu&=& 0,2\\
&\vec{g}&=& \SI{10}{\m\per\s\squared}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]